# Is there a way to get links of downloads initiated by applications?

Tags: visual-studio, networking, xamarin, download

My connection is spotty and I'm updating Xamarin through Visual Studio, I'd like to know if there is way to take a peek on the network activity of VS and get a direct link.
Is that possible, is there any tools for this?

Comment: You may use a packet sniffer like Wireshark. However, if if you get the download link, I am not sure if you will be able to install the update correctly. See this question to understand how to isolate packets generated by an application. http://serverfault.com/q/442692/348131

Answer (score 1):

The xamarin installer gets links from this document https://static.xamarin.com/installer_assets/v3/Windows/Universal/InstallationManifest.xml

Thanks @BOOMik very much, http://download.xamarin.com/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.0.3.214.msi (Current version)